# Can you have a formula remove zero values from a calculation?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have written the formula below, which is calculating the log average of 60 cells (I have shortened the formula here for simplicity) :

```
=10*LOG(((10^(F4/10))+(10^(F5/10))+(10^(F6/10))+(10^(F7/10))...)/60
```

I want the formula to discount a given term `(10^(F4/10))` from the averaging calculation if the value is zero.

I know that for an arithmetic average you can use the function `AVERAGEIF(range,"<>0")` but I can't figure out how to (or even if it's possible) to adapt this to the above formula.

I can't just delete the zero terms before averaging, as the excel sheet is pulling the data from other sheets in the workbook, and and I need to maintain a certain number of rows within each sheet. This is because the raw data is downloaded from an external piece of hardware, and exported to excel in a certain format.

I am using microsoft office 365 business.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use SUMPRODUCT to not only skip the `0` but to shorten the formula:

```
=10*LOG(SUMPRODUCT((F4:F63>0)*(10^(F4:F63/10)))/60)
```

If you want to exclude them from the denominator as well:

```
=10*LOG(SUMPRODUCT((F4:F63>0)*(10^(F4:F63/10)))/SUMPRODUCT(--(F4:F63>0)))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, however neither formula is returning the correct answer.

Comment: Well since I do not know your inputs and your expected output, I cannot verify.  You will need to step through the formula using Evaluate formula on the formula tab and see where it is going wrong.

Comment: As a check, if I have values of 6,6,6,6 & 6 and use =10*LOG(((10^(R4/10))+(10^(R5/10))+(10^(R6/10))+(10^(R7/10))+(10^(R8/10)))/5) I get 6, with the formula you suggested I get 4.15. If I had 6,6,0,6 & 6 I should still get 6 as the answer. I think the terms need to be calculated individually; if you do (10^(6/10))+ (10^(6/10))+(10^(6/10))+(10^(6/10))+(10^(6/10)) you get 19.9 , whereas (10^((6+6+6+6+6)/10)) gives you 1000; I think this is what the formula you suggested is doing.

Comment: @PeterYoung but to be fair the `()` matched what you had in your OP and your comment is different.  The answer now matches your comment.

Comment: I have a fresh problem with this, the formula works perfectly when removing zeros, however a quirk with my data means that the lowest value I can have is actually 7, and it is these that I need to calculation to not calculate. I thought it would be as simple as changing the >0 to >7 but it does not seem to be working. Can you think what I might be doing wrong here?

Comment: It works for me, Make sure you replace both `>0` with `>7` on the second formula.

Comment: I think the problem may be that the formula that is giving the result is calculated through an Add In; when I re-do the calculation long hand in excel and then reference the result the formula you provided works for any value. However I am getting an issue where the if all of the values in the range are below 7, then the formula is returning a #div/0! error. Can I add an IF argument to this to say if all of the values are below 7 then return 0?

Comment: @PeterYoung add an IFERROR wrapper: `=IFERROR(...,0)` where `...` is the formula above.